# Use requirejs modules as es6 module

Tags: javascript, requirejs, ecmascript-6, commonjs, es6-module-loader

I'm trying to migrate my project to ES6 modules, but I met an issue.

I have 3rd party script that use modules with help of requirejs. Let name it 3rdParty.js. It was obtained via bower, so there is no ability and wish to update it.

Is there any way to import 3rdParty.js, using ES6 syntax without removing *define* functions from file?

Comment: What module loader are you using?

Comment: I'm trying to migrate my project from **requirejs** modules to **es6** modules using [grunt-es6-module-transpiler](https://github.com/joefiorini/grunt-es6-module-transpiler). 
But I have requirejs modules which not related to project code base. Is there any ability to use them with es6 modules?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[SystemJS](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs) can load es6 modules and AMD or CommonJS together.

It has format detector, so you can just import module via System.import, and then library takes care about module formats